# How do I create a random number that remains constant and doesn't change in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to have a few circles drawn on the screen that do not move after initialization. Right now it is constantly drawing them to the screen instead of keeping them there. Here's the code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    //location
    const r = random(100, 900);
    const r2 = random(900, 100);
    //size
    const rS = random(50, 250);
    const rS2 = random(250, 50);
    //draw the ellipse with parameters
    ellipse(r, r2, rS, rS2);
  }
```

(This is with the p5.js library)

Comment: Your code loops exactly once, so it looks like it will draw one ellipse. What do you mean by "constantly drawing them to the screen instead of keeping them there"?

Comment: @kmoser I probably should've noted that it's in the draw function because that's the only function that will show something on the screen. Putting the code in the setup function briefly shows the ellipse, but then the draw function immediately colors the background over it.

edit: Just fixed the issue by putting background() into the setup. However this will probably create issues later.

edit 2: Alright found an issue. Since it doesn't refresh the background the thing that I have display on the screen to the mouse coordinates will leave a trail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your code is in the `draw()` function, which is called multiple times a second. Since you call `random()` every single time, it creates new parameters every single time. Instead, you should assign parameters to a variable somewhere else (like in the `setup` function) and then use those in the draw function. Something like:

```js
var ellipses = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    ellipses.push({
      r: random(100, 300),
      r2: random(300, 100),
      rS: random(50, 250),
      rS2: random(250, 50)
    });
  }  
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  //location
  //draw the ellipse with parameters
  ellipses.forEach(function (e) {
    ellipse(e.r, e.r2, e.rS, e.rS2);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```